# Why is the Neyman estimator for the variance of diff in means conservatively biased?

Tags: variance, t-test, standard-error

Numerous lecture slides and papers claim that the Neyman estimator for the variance of difference in means is conservatively biased (i.e., the estimate is larger than the true variance). I must be missing something obvious, as it doesn't make sense to me.

For example, see [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20200126221259/http://www.macartan.nyc/experiment/neyman/) and [here](https://www2.stat.duke.edu/courses/Spring14/sta320.01/Class7.pdf).

The variance of the difference in means is $1/N(S_1^2 + S_2^2 + 2S_{12})$. The Neyman estimator drops the covariance, which is surely positive. Why is using that estimator conservative?

Comment: "Conservative," if it has any meaning at all, depends on the default standpoint of the speaker: it could mean biased up or biased down.  In light of that ambiguity, could you provide more context?

Comment: Thanks, I just added more clarification. Is this clearer?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that, except for the case of a constant treatment effect, the covariance is negative.

First, note that

$$
Var(X - Y) = Var(X) + Var(Y) - 2 \cdot Cov(X, Y)
$$

It turns out the covariance term is negative, and there's an intuitive explanation. If assignment was independent, then the covariance term would be zero. This would occur in a randomized experiment where assignment is based on a fixed ratio, e.g. you flip a coin to determine each assignment.

In a completely randomized experiment, though, assignment is not independent. Previous assignments tell us something about subsequent assignments. For example, if you know $n-1$ assignments, you know all the assignments. Knowing more means less variance (at least theoretically).

Returning to the formula above, under Neyman's finite sampling approach, you also have the finite population correction terms so you end up with

$$
\begin{aligned}
Var(\bar{t} - \bar{c}) &= \frac{S_t^2}{n_t} \cdot (1 - \frac{n_t}{n}) + \frac{S_c^2}{n_c} \cdot (1 - \frac{n_c}{n}) + \frac{2 }{n (n - 1)}\sum_{i=1}^n (t_i -  \bar{t}) \cdot (c_i - \bar{c})
\end{aligned}
$$

The covariance can't be estimated because the same unit is never observed under the treatment and control regime (simultaneously). Thus, more algebra is need, and this get you back to $Var(\bar{t}) + Var(\bar{c})$ minus another term that can't be estimated but which is negative. For details see my derivation [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/604522/362671).

Also note that for a super-population model, the Neyman estimate is not conservative because the treatment and control groups can be assumed to be independent and thus there is no covariance term.